# What is 林家パー子ばり?

Tags: words, definitions

What is **林家パー子ばり**?

A colleague used it in a complex context, but I have found many another occurrences, including [this one](http://www.saitohome.co.jp/wp/blog/2013/09/21/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E5%AD%90%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93/) in the very simple context of a self-presentation:

> おもしろそうな場面には必ずカメラを持って「写真撮らせてくださ～い」と現れます。
>
> **林家パー子ばり**のアンテナです。
>   自宅の家電もほとんどピンク色だそうです(笑)。

What is the meaning of **林家パー子ばり** in this context?
No definition on the first two pages of Google.
It seems to have something to do with laughing and the color pink.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ばり is an uncommon 接尾語 which means "like".

http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/180011/m0u/

> ばり【張り】［接尾］
>   ２ 名詞や人名を表す語の下に付いて、それに似ている、または、それに似せているという意を表す。「西鶴―の文」「左翼―の主張」

So 「林家パー子ばりのアンテナ」 is "an antenna just like (that of) [林家パー子](http://ameblo.jp/peeparko/)".

She is known for the pink dress and the fondness for gossiping, so アンテナ here means "ability to find something interesting, or catch up on gossips".